# Yii::app()->user->checkAccess() в beforeAction выдает что-то странное - почему?

Tags: yii, access, controller, users, action

Как в Yii 1.x до выполнения действия контролера проверить: имеет ли права пользователь на выполнение этого действия и если не имеет выполнить определенный код?

Пробую так, в protected\components\Controller.php:

```
class Controller extends CController
{

    protected function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if ( !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($action->id) ) {
            // здесь мой код
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

к сожалению код не срабатывает, потому что `Yii::app()->user->checkAccess` выдает `FALSE` когда должно быть `TRUE` и наоборот.

Что не так?

Comment: checkAccess принимает в себя вроде имя роли, а не идентификатор....а вторым параметром вроде и ID передать можно http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#checkAccess-detail

Comment: не не, там же написано про первый параметр: "the name of the operation that need access check." - это точно не роль, а название операции. Наверное действие контролера (action) нельзя передавать туда, только название операции определенной через бизнес правила.

Comment: ну да, я типа этого и имел в виду, что операция)) операции которые ты сам где-либо определяешь может это поможет http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.auth

Comment: естественно я смотрел раздел справки ) просто была надажда на checkAccess, теперь получается совсем не знаю что делать и как быть. А задача то банальная...

Comment: единственный вариант наверное городить огород с проходом по accessRules() и для каждого правла там создавать $auth->createOperation() чтобы потом использовать Yii::app()->user->checkAccess